# Python get remaining runoff voting

Tags: python, dictionary

I am a little stuck on writing a function for a project. This function takes a dictionary of candidates who's values are the number of votes they received. I then have to return a set containing the remaining_candidates. In other words the candidate with the least amount of votes should not be in the set being returned and if for example all of the candidates have the same votes, the set should be empty. I am having trouble getting started here.
For example I know I can sort the dictionary like so:

```
x = min(canadites, key=canadites.__getitem__)
```

but that will not work if the candidates have the same value, as it just pops up the last one in the dict.

Any ideas?

Update: To make things clear.

Lets say I have the following dictionary:

```
canadites = {'X':22,'Y':1, 'Z':0}
```

Ideally the function should return a set containing only X and Y. But if Y and Z where both 1

```
x = min(canadites, key=canadites.__getitem__)
```

seems to only return Z

Comment: Add examples, It will make your question clearer

Comment: Where's the problem? If you want to remove a key from a dictionary you can use `del dictionary[key]` or use `dict.pop(key)`. Read [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict "Official reference for dict")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cleaner to create a new dict instead of popping items from the old one:

```
>>> d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'd':3}
>>> min_val = min(d.values())
>>> {k:v for k,v in d.items() if v > min_val}
{'b': 2, 'd': 3}
```

In python2, `itervalues` and `iteritems` would be more efficient, although this is a micro-optimization in most cases.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, I am new to the comprehension, could you explain this a little more.